# highchart combine pie and spiderweb

Tags: highcharts, pie-chart

I'm trying to create a pie chart with a spiderweb on top. 
I'm not sure how to do it with highchart.

This is what i would like to end up with using highchart
[image: Piechart with a spiderweb]

The problem with the current solution are the spiderweb lines which are not place inside their "slice".

This is what i got so far: 
https://jsfiddle.net/bormeth/bk7c3bgs/

```js
$(function() {
  $('#container').highcharts({
    chart: {
      polar: true
    },

    title: {
      text: 'Pie / Spiderweb',
      x: -50
    },

    xAxis: {
      visible: false
    },

    yAxis: [{
      min: 0,
      max: 100,
      visible: false
    }],

    tooltip: {
      shared: true
    },

    legend: {
      align: 'right',
      verticalAlign: 'top',
      y: 70,
      layout: 'vertical'
    },

    series: [{
      size: '100%',
      type: 'pie',
      name: 'Team',
      data: [{
        y: 21,
        color: '#9e0624',
        name: 'Manager'
      }, {
        y: 17,
        color: '#d14b21',
        name: 'Entrepreneur'
      }, {
        y: 9,
        color: '#ce8815',
        name: 'Innovator - Creator'
      }, {
        y: 23,
        color: '#648964',
        name: 'Supportive'
      }, {
        y: 18,
        color: '#011d4b',
        name: 'Organiser'
      }, {
        y: 12,
        color: '#43044e',
        name: 'Analyst'
      }]
    }, {
      type: 'line',
      data: [20, 2, 13, 30, 14, 22],
      color: 'green',
      name: 'User'
    }]

  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="//code.highcharts.com/highcharts-more.js"></script>
<script src="//code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>
<div id="container" style="min-width: 400px; max-width: 600px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto"></div>
```

I hope that someone can point me in the right direction. 
I've tried using a standard pie chart and just add the lines on top, but the lines are not rendered as a spiderweb unless its inside a polar chart.

Comment: I have never actually seen this before. What is the use case for doing this? What determines which slice a spider series goes into? What happens if a PIE slice is really small? Are you sure you want to have this kind of merge?

Comment: wergeld: It's used for comparing users vs. an entire team. 
This way i'm able to show how a team is divided into categories but also how a user is compared to the team. 
It's very rare that the slice is too small for the web to fit inside it. The image shown i've created with d3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to translate scales between the pie and the polar chart. I think that much more sense make using only a polar chart and its scale - with the addition of [axis.plotBands](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/xAxis.plotBands) and [axis.plotLines](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/xAxis.plotLines).

See the [live example](https://jsfiddle.net/h06yLtft/) - code and some and steps are below.

You data:

```
  var data = [20, 2, 13, 30, 14, 22];
  var dataLen = data.length;
  var pieData = [{
    y: 21,
    color: '#9e0624',
    name: 'Manager'
  }, {
    y: 17,
    color: '#d14b21',
    name: 'Entrepreneur'
  }, {
    y: 9,
    color: '#ce8815',
    name: 'Innovator - Creator'
  }, {
    y: 23,
    color: '#648964',
    name: 'Supportive'
  }, {
    y: 18,
    color: '#011d4b',
    name: 'Organiser'
  }, {
    y: 12,
    color: '#43044e',
    name: 'Analyst'
  }];
```

Creating plot bands and plot lines:

```
var plotBands = pieData.slice(1).reduce((plotBands, point, i) => {
  var prevY = plotBands[i].to;

  plotBands.push({
    from: prevY,
    to: prevY + point.y / 100 * dataLen,
    color: point.color,
    innerRadius: '0%'
  });

  return plotBands;
}, [{
  from: 0,
  to: pieData[0].y / 100 * dataLen,
  color: pieData[0].color,
  name: pieData[0].name,
  innerRadius: '0%'
}]);

var plotLines = plotBands.map(plotBand => {
  return {
    value: plotBand.from,
    color: 'white',
    width: 1.5,
    zIndex: 6
  }
});
```

Positioning you data to be in the middle of the polar slice

```
 var positionedData = data.map((value, i) => {
  var x1 = plotLines[i].value,
  x2 = i + 1 === dataLen ? dataLen : plotLines[i + 1].value,
  d = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(x1 - x2, 2));

  return [Number((x1 + d / 2).toFixed(2)), value, pieData[i].name, pieData[i].y]
});
```

Creating labels for the slices:

```
var labels = {};
  pieData.forEach((p, i) => {
  labels[positionedData[i][0]] = p.name
});
```

Chart config:

```
  $('#container').highcharts({
chart: {
  polar: true
},

xAxis: {
  plotBands: plotBands,
  plotLines: plotLines,
  gridLineWidth: 0,
  min: 0,
  max: dataLen,
  labels: {
    formatter: function() {
      return labels[this.value];
    }
  },
  tickPositions: positionedData.map(p => p[0]),
  showLastLabel: true
},

yAxis: [{
  min: 0,
  max: Math.max.apply(null, data),
  visible: false,
  endOnTick: false
}],

tooltip: {
  formatter: function() {
    var headerF = '<span style="font-size: 10px">' + this.key + ': ' + this.point.pieY + '</span><br/>';
    var pointF = '<span style="color:' + this.color + '">\u25CF</span> ' + this.series.name + ': <b>' + this.y + '</b><br/>';

    return headerF + pointF;
  }
},

series: [{
  keys: ['x', 'y', 'name', 'pieY'],
  data: positionedData,
  color: 'green',
  name: 'User'
}]

});
```

Comment: Thank you so much, it looks perfect!  
I like the idea of using the plotBands and the plotLines, somewhat makes it easier to see what actually happens.

Comment: How would you add another spiderweb using your example?

Comment: Create another series - for each series you need to find centers - see [example](https://jsfiddle.net/h06yLtft/1/)